# Checking associativity prop. of Group, in which order

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is given [here](http://faculty.uml.edu/klevasseur/webwork_ads/s-11-1.html) that depending on situation, need to check the property of associativity before or after that of checking that of identity and inverse (effectively, identity, as the page further says that identity need be found before inverse). I have new clue to know further there. Also, submitting an image of the same page:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to check the associativity of these, it's pretty simple.

$(x*y)*z = (x+y+46)*z = (x+y+46)+z+46 = x+y+z+92$

$x*(y*z)$ can be easily computed using the same logic.

Comment: The web page asks about : depending on situation, check the property in order after or before that of finding identity, as it further says that identity needs to be found before ascertaining inverse. Also, my title is clear about when to put finding associativity before identity or vice-versa, depending on the situation.

Comment: So I think the problem is simply asking you to prove associativity, then show inverses, then show identity. When proving these exist for a general structure, the order isn't necessarily important I believe. However, some implications can be more helpful than others.

Comment: I hope you meant : "prove associativity, then show identity, then show  inverses". Also, if the page states then there must be a reason for stating about the situation in which one or the other order is to be taken up. This is what you have meant by "more helpful than other(sequence/ordering of checking)". But, when is the key.

Comment: Yes. I would say the key is kind of intuition. If you feel that showing associativity would be easier with the introduction of an identity element, then show the identity first and follow it with assoc. There's no general heuristic.